# SQL & PHP Unique Number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, uid

I will be using the GET method with NFC to pull some data, I want to populate a database with a ton of unique digits, I don't mind them having keywords in them like

```
TOM05543
TOM04423
KEL04432
KAL43242
```

What would be the best method of doing this and filling my database with these unique ID's before hand?

Comment: Doesn't an auto-incremented value work for you?

Comment: @apokryfos I want the numbers to be unique and not easily guessed, It's not a top priority to have them that secure as it won't hold sensitive data. I just want it in a way that its not 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc... Also keeping them short and adding keywords to populate a larger amount of unique id's

Comment: Have you tried something or wanted code by SO users.

Comment: Do they have to adhere to any particular pattern? Taking the first X characters of the md5 hash of sequentials numbers + a salt might fit, but it'll end up as a random (-ish) string of letters and numbers rather than anything very readable.

Comment: @RohanKumar I'm fairly new to PHP and I've had a play around with things, I just like to learn the best practice instead of earning bad habits of the wrong way ;)

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php with the more entropy flag. It's not guaranteed unique, but the probability it's not unique is so low that it's probably non-existent.

Comment: As I recall one of the greatest problem in IT is generating really unique ids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a PHP function which can generate a random apha numeric code and check that code exist in DB table or not. If exist then function call recursively until unique code will be generated. And insert uniquely generated record in DB table.

```
<?php
//DB connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

//Function to generate unique alpha numeric code
function generateRandomNumer($con,$len=8){
    $randomString = substr(MD5(time()),$len);

    //Check newly generated Code exist in DB table or not.
    $query = "select * from table_name where col_name='".$randomString."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $resultCount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($resultCount>0){
        //IF code is already exist then function will call it self until unique code has been generated and inserted in Db.
        generateRandomNumer($con);
    }else{
        //Unique generated code will be inserted in DB.
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (col_name) VALUES ('".$randomString."')");
    }
}

//Loop to insert number of unique code in DB.
//NUM_OF_RECORD_YOU_WANT_TO_INSERT define constant which contain number of unique codes you wants to insert in DB. 
for($i=0;$i<NUM_OF_RECORD_YOU_WANT_TO_INSERT;$i++){
    generateRandomNumer($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Rahul.

Comment: Good answer, yet the select's random string needs to be quoted. That will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah Thanks.. Corrected.

Comment: This is dangerous... There is no fallback to prevent the script from getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the solution offered at http://guid.us/GUID/PHP which is :

```
function getGUID(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    }else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
            .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12)
            .chr(125);// "}"
        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

More information on GUIDs can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

I do realise that a GUID is not technically unique, however the chance that a good random number generator generates 2 identical GUIDs is about 1 in 2^122 which means if you generate a GUID every 1 millisecond you'd hit the first duplicate in about 10^26 years.

This has the advantage of not needing to check the database if the key is already there or not since we assume it's not.